# How to update twig variable from jquery?

Tags: php, html, jquery, twig

how to update information of variable 'mark' in twig?
New information comes from jquery on button click

in index.php

```
  $input_vars = [
        'lang' => $lang,
        'stats' => $stats,
        'id' => $id,
        //This variable should be updated
        'mark' => $user_marks
    ];

    echo $twig->render('player_stats.html', $input_vars);
```

in player_stats.html  (temlpate html page)

```
        ////if a user click on the button

        $("#sait_marks").click(function() {
            var user_id = {{ id }};
            var user_marks = {{ mark|json_encode|raw }};
            getmarks(user_id, user_marks);
        });

        function getmarks(id, marks) {
            $.ajax({
                url:'/json_get_marks.php',
                method:'post',
                data:{query1:id, query2:marks},
                success:function(data){
                    resultObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    ///Where to redirect data?
                    $("#table1").trigger("update").trigger("resize");
                }
            });
        }
```

in json_get_marks.php

```
///a new mark data
echo json_encode($new_mark);
```

Comment: Twig is rendered serverside, so can't really modify the generated template after it's rendered. Maybe you can do `window.user_marks = ...` and then update that value since `window` is a global

Comment: Are you using any sort of datatables because u do `$("#table1").trigger("update").trigger("resize");`?

Comment: @apokryfos OP is using ajax so he/she is able to render any template with `twig` in the calling PHP "endpoint"

Comment: The table is loaded with data initially from the database, but later from the api

Comment: wrap the table with like a section give it an ID, render the table in `get_marks` and update the html of the wrapper

Comment: @DarkBee yes I am aware of that however as far as I know Twig templates are rendered serverside and can't be altered clientside once rendered so I suggested a way to leverage the window global to modify the initially rendered variable. Sending an entire template via Ajax would probably be wasteful

Comment: Yeah but seems OP is just rendering a table and is not using any javascript plugin to update/create a datatable, so it's easier to just render the table in a controller called by the ajax call. Keep in my mind twig has a function `renderBlock` to just render a specific block from a template